# Necessary elements for android graphics

Tags: android

All, Forgive me just learning `Android` Graphics, And I just knew a little about it. I can draw something like line with `Paint` which hosted in the `Canvas`,

```
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.puzzle_background));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);


    Paint dark = new Paint();
    dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));
    Paint hilite = new Paint();
    hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));
    Paint light = new Paint();
    light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));
    // Draw the minor grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, light);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), light);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                hilite);
    }
    // Draw the major grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 != 0)
            continue;
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, dark);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                hilite);
    }
```

But I don't know What are the necessary elements if I want to draw something in the `Android`.And Is the `Paint` one of the necessary elements? thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve? Canvas class is your palette and Paint is your brush

Comment: I meaned If I want to draw graphic in the android, These two `Canvas` and `Paint` are the necessary instance to be initialized ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three ways that I know of to draw in Android.

1- Overriding `onDraw` (as you did) which provides you with the canvas of the View to draw with on the View's surface. This is used for simple drawings as the code runs in the main Thread.

2- Subclass `SurfaceView`, which provides a separate thread for drawing (provides a Canvas as well of a Surface that you draw on), for medium load drawing since it has a separate thread, so it can be faster than 1.

3- `OpenglSurfaceView`, which is a different concept, in which you create a 3D scene and render it directly using the GPU. This is for heavy weight drawing, since talking to the GPU directly enables much faster animations, specially in 3D games.

As I said in my comment, `Canvas` is your palette, which provides you with basic tools to draw lines, circles, images, ...etc. While, `Paint` is your brush, which lets you determine stroke width, color, Text size and fonts, ...etc. you may not need to change Paint object if you are satisfied with the defaults of `Canvas`. Your drawing board is the View's surface.

Comment: Thanks your excellent answer, I think it will be appreciated and helpful to the guys who just learned the android ,like me .thanks again.